# spring gets hanged on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

rails c gets stuck on local.

Ruby version: 3.1.0 (same on 3.0.0)

Rails version : 6.1.4

Spring version: 4.0.0 (same on 3.1.0)

Stack trace

```
s$ rails c
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
^C/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `verify_server_version'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:62:in `run'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:42:in `warm_run'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `call'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/s/Projects/flinket/moneycapital/bin/spring:10:in `require'
    from /Users/s/Projects/flinket/moneycapital/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/s/Projects/flinket/moneycapital/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try updating your bundler -- ```bundle update --bundler``` https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5234

Comment: this warning is because of 3.1.0, but the issues (which is getting stuck) persist in 3.0.0 as well. already tried updating bundler but nothing resolves with that.

Comment: try this ```spring stop``` then ```rails c```

Comment: already tried that, doesnt work.